# Проблема с watch в angularjs, считывание значений модели

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

у input есть поле с  моделью при ручном вводе

```
 $scope.$watch('testmodel', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                console.log(newValue);
            });
```

Всё срабатывает, если в это поле значение вставляет скрипт на jquery то watch не работает
Как поймать вставку значения скриптом

Comment: не используйте jquery для этого и все. Можете рассказать зачем вы вставляете значение с помощью jQuery, а не ангуляра?

Comment: ulogin пытаюсь подружить c angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После вставки скриптом на jquery выполните для этого инпута `.trigger('change')`

Comment: Золотой ты мой человек, помог с костылём спасибо =)